# `date::parse`: no matching overloaded function found

Tags: c++, visual-studio, date

I have installed [`date`](https://github.com/HowardHinnant/date) library using `vcpkg install date:x64-windows` and I use `find_package(date CONFIG REQUIRED)` to use the library in my cross-platform project. I successfully find the library (`date_FOUND="1"`) in `C:\Dev\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows\include\date\date.h`.

My app uses `set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 20)` and when I build it using Visual Studio 2022 community, the compiler complains with the following error. I am simply converting a string to a time_point given a format.

```
// code:
const std::string timeString = "2020-12-18 12:30:45";
const char *fmt = "%F";
std::istringstream in(timeString);
std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::system_clock> timeStamp;
in >> date::parse(fmt, timeStamp);

// Compiler message
error C2672: 'date::parse': no matching overloaded function found
C:\Dev\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows\include\date/date.h(8169): note: could be 'unknown-type date::parse(const CharT *,Parsable &,std::basic_string<CharT,Traits,Alloc> &,std::chrono::minutes &)'
```

It was linked using:

```
target_link_libraries(main PRIVATE date::date date::date-tz)
```

I am developing a cross-platform app and therefore, I have installed date library in linux `./vcpkg install date:x64-linux`.

***I can successfully build the same code with `gcc11`, and it works in linux***.

I love this library and I would love to be able to use it. I'd appreciate it if I could get any help on this issue.

Comment: How can we tell you that without seeing the code?  You have evidently tried to call a version of `date::parse` that doesn't match any of the existing templates.

Comment: It is not the issue with the code as it works in linux. I am assuming the library is not installed or setup correctly for use in Windows.

Comment: @afp_2008 not a correct sillogism. alot of code may not work like that because of UB invoking (e.g. `using namespace date`) and implementation details. Btw, `fmt` is a used name in `std`

Comment: looks like it failed to find `struct date::parse_manip<std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::system_clock>, ChartT, std::char_traits<CharT>, std::allocator<CharT>>` Question is, why?

Comment: @Swift-FridayPie _"`fmt` is a used name in `std`"_ -- are you sure? There is `std::format` but what is `std::fmt`?

Comment: This library was voted into `std::chrono` for C++20, and MSVC has implemented it.  Can you use `std::chrono` instead?  [Demo.](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/feWqY19r7)

Comment: @HowardHinnant I would like to have one code that works in both Windows and Linux. I tried defining `#ifdef WIN32 namespace mydate = std::chrono #ifdef LINUX namespace mydate = date` but I ran into several other issues because I also use `date::format` and other functions of `date::`. The latest version of `gcc` available for centos7 is `devtoolset11` and I think it would be a long wait for me to get to `gcc14`.

Comment: Ok, makes sense.  I would either pursue the namespace switch as you describe.  Or possibly drop from `date::parse` down to `date::from_stream`.  `from_steam` offers all of the `parse` functionality, but is not as nice syntax.  And that may work around the issues you're seeing with `date::parse` and MSVC.